# Partial fractions to solve integrals

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

$$\int_0^x\frac{1}{(a-x)(b-x)}\,dx=\frac{1}{b-a}\left( \ln\frac{1}{a-x}-\ln\frac{1}{b-x} \right)$$

I'm trying to figure out how the above fractions are equal to each other. I know they use partial fraction "rules", however I don't quite understand the method in this case. Also we are not looking for the constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You have an $x$ in the boundary and an $x$ in the integrand. Typically this isn't OK. You probably want the bound to be a different variable, like $t$ or something. Moreover, you may want to include the question written out, as other users may downvote you for attaching an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$\frac {1}{a-x}-\frac {1}{b-x}=$$

$$\frac {b-x-a+x}{(a-x)(b-x)}=$$

$$\frac {b-a}{(  a-x)( b-x  )} $$

Comment: I understand what you do but how can you derive the first expression? I mean the two partial fractions in your comment?

Answer (score -1):

it is $$\frac{1}{(a-x)(b-x)}={\frac {1}{ \left( a-b \right)  \left( -a+x \right) }}-{\frac {1}{
 \left( a-b \right)  \left( -b+x \right) }}
$$