# Strange substitution in integral using partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions, chemistry

> Let $[A]_0=a$ and $[B]_0=b$, then $[A]=a-x$ and $[B]=b-x$.
>
> $$\int_0^x \frac{1}{(a-x)(b-x)}dx = \frac{1}{b-a}\left(\ln\frac{1}{a-x} - \ln\frac{1}{b-x}\right)$$
>
> Evaluating the integral gives us:
>
> $$\int_0^x \frac{1}{([A]_0-x)([B]_0-x)}dx = \frac{1}{[B]_0-[A]_0}\left(\ln\frac{[A]_0}{[A]_0-x} - \ln\frac{[B]_0}{[B]_0-x}\right)$$

In an assignment I have to mathematically prove a law in chemistry. Some of the math behind it can be seen in the above quote. However, I don't understand how they can replace the nummerators in the parenthesis with [A]o and [B]o. Is there any mathemathical/logical explanation to that? Is it due to that the whole fraction is equal to respectively [A]o and [B]o? Hope it makes sense..

Comment: At the top of your image, it states that $[A]_0$ is $a$.  That means that $[A]_0$ and $a$ are identical, and can be used interchangeably.  Ditto $[B]_0$ and $b$.  That is what "equals" means.  As an aside, you really need to format your question.  [This question on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) should help you get setup with MathJax.  Also, didn't you *just* ask [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559066/partial-fractions-to-solve-integrals/2559071)?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @Mark Indeed, but the answer to that question would have been addressed if the OP had answered Alfred Yerger's question about the upper limit of integration when this question was [first posed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559066/partial-fractions-to-solve-integrals/2559071).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a mysterious substitution, but actually what's happening is that there are additional terms that appear when you evaluate the complete definite integral. These extra terms contribute new terms to the numerator.

---

Let's take a look at the integrals involved. The indefinite integral of

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(a-x)(b-x)}$$

is

$$F(x) = \int f(x)dx = \frac{1}{b-a}\left[\log\frac{1}{a-x} - \log\frac{1}{b-x}\right]$$

(which you can show using the method of partial fractions for integration).

In particular, we can evaluate the *definite* integral

$$\int_0^L f(x)dx = F(L) - F(0) = \frac{1}{b-a}\left[\log\frac{1}{a-L} - \log\frac{1}{b-L}\right] - \frac{1}{b-a}\left[\log\frac{1}{a} - \log\frac{1}{b}\right]$$

We can combine terms, then use the fact that $\log(p) - \log(q) = \log(p/q)$ to simplify the result:

$$= \frac{1}{b-a}\left[\left(\log\frac{1}{a-L} - \log\frac{1}{a}\right) - \left(\log\frac{1}{b-L} - \log\frac{1}{b}\right)\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{b-a} \left[ \log\frac{a}{a-L} - \log\frac{b}{b-L}\right]$$

which is the result you're looking for.

Hope this helps!

---

P.S.  I think the first equation in your question could have been more clearly written as an indefinite integral as shown below. (That is, writing $\int$ instead of $\int_0^x$).  It might even have been a typo in the original.
$$\int \frac{1}{(b-x)(a-x)}dx = \frac{1}{b-a}\left[\log\frac{1}{a-x} - \log\frac{1}{b-x}\right]$$